# How to handle features with hierarchy in regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, predictive-models

I'm trying to fit a regression model to predict the total expense of department with predictor variables being the headcount at different levels within the department. Level 1 to level 5 are the different hierarchy levels with 1 being the highest and 5 being the lowest. It is intuitive that the number of people in the higher level is lesser than that in the middle and lower levels. Due to the difference in magnitude, the regression parameters gets biased to the levels with high headcount numbers. I tried regularization but unfortunately couldn't achieve the best fit. I was looking to add weights to the features but unable to get a hold on the right weighing technique. Looking for suggestions on the appropriate models. Attaching the snap of how my data looks.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. If you assume cost is a function of people hired, then of course it is determined by the number of people at lower levels. Every department presumably has a single head, whether it employs 10 people or 10000. So basically - rethink what you are trying to achieve with this regression. Actually, there's insufficient information here to judge whether you need regression at all.

Comment: please break down your claims (adding to the question). what do you mean by biased? what do you mean couldn't achieve best fit? in a straight (not regularised) linear regression did you check the uncertainties. I would expect the uncertainties to be higher on the coefficients of level 1/2, which perhaps reflects why managerial salaries can rocket - they have minimal effect on total cost.

Comment: @mkt Thank you very much for your explanation. Let me try to be more clear on the objective. 
Objective: To build a predictive model that takes headcount structure at different levels as input to predict/estimate the potential cost associated with them and simulate different headcount scenarios.   An example to this is --  if my level 1 headcount increased by +2 and all other levels remains the same, what would be my cost implication? This can be scaled up by adjusting headcounts in other levels as well.

Comment: @seanv507 Thank you. So it goes like this. By biased I mean, the magnitude of the coefficients of level 3 and 4 and much higher than that of levels 1 and 2 due to its higher numbers relatively. As a result when I simulate adding 1 person to level 4 shows a great increase in the cost whereas adding 1 person to level 1 hardly shows any difference in the cost. Ideally the cost of the VP in an organization is higher than that of a senior engineer and this reality is taking a hit in my model.

Comment: It would help if you add more details about the data. For e.g., why do you need statistics as opposed to just calculating it based on salary information? How many different companies do you have data for? What are these levels and what are the ranges of numbers in each, roughly?

Comment: What are these levels and why are you using them?

Comment: please add/update the question/rather than in individual comments.

Answer (score 1):

> the magnitude of the coefficients of level 3 and 4 and much higher
> than that of levels 1 and 2 due to its higher numbers relatively

this is not bias.

as others have noted, one would expect the coefficients to roughly correspond to salary.

So this may be due to your modelling (regularisation) and/or correlations between your levels data.

In particular imagine if your data only consists of level 1 and level 5 employees in fixed proportion 1: 10. ie

company A has 1 level 1, and 10 level 5.

company B has 2 level 1 and 20 level 5.
...

in this case the data is perfectly collinear, and eg a model with only level 5 input can capture all the variation. eg say salary of level 1 is 100 and level 5 is 20. then a coefficient of 30 on level 5 (and 0 on level 1) will still match the total cost. since $100n + 20.10.n =30.10.n$

note that L2 regularisation will prefer this solution (0 salary for level 1, 30 for level 5) to the correct one (30^2 < 100^2 + 20^2),

[I am not saying this is the optimal solution, but hopefully you get the idea, why you are getting lower numbers for your level 1s etc]

This is the problem with observational data. In an experiment, you would create orthogonal columns (varying level 1, independent from level 5 etc), in observational data, you have to consider the correlations between your variables - there is practically no company with a level 1 employee and zero level 5...

Comment: Thank you @seanv507. This is very useful!